# using .split to parse file name

Tags: python, split

I am comparing two list and would like to compare the names of each element in the list regardless of the file extensions. To do this i currently manually delete that extensions based on its length. Id like to automatically ignore everything past the . in a file name so it works regardless of the file type.

```
for x in Localfilenmamelist:
    try:
        Remotefilenamelist.remove(x[:-3] + '.gz')
    except:
        pass
```

I've tried x.split(".",[0]) but it does not work. I think its my syntax but as I'm fairly new to python I'm not sure whats wrong with it.

Comment: use `os.path.splitext()`, and remember: it doesn't work in-place. A |mcve] would be required.

Comment: Please improve your question by giving examples of expected inputs and outputs

Comment: Do you care about filepaths or just about the base filename (minus extension)? And from the looks of your code, are you trying to remove any file from the `Remotefilenamelist` that exists in `Localfilenamelist`?

Comment: @birryree Just the base filename minus extension. and Yes that is the goal.

Comment: this is _very_ close to the original linked question. I had came up with almost the same solution (but I didn't answer because 1) no valid attempt from OP and 2) the duplicate is quickly adapted to ignore extensions from both sides.